# Change gradle default directory to project directory

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In below sample, the file name output will be at home directory, how can I change the default directory to current project directory?

```
 tasks.register('hello')  {
  doLast {
    String dirname = "demo";
    String filename = "hello.txt";

    String abspath = new File(dirname, filename).getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(abspath);
  }
}
```

Current output is:

```
/home/user/.gradle/daemon/7.4.2/demo/hello.txt
```

But what I want is:

```
/project/path/demo/hello.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [`project.getRootDir()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getRootDir--) - it points to the project's root dir.